# Disable .dev redirection to HTTPS in Firefox

Tags: firefox, https

In February, Firefox began to force `.dev` requests to `https`.

Is there a way to disable this? I'd rather update one config in a browser than the dozen or so changes I'll need to make in order to support HTTPS on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Stop using `.dev` as it now a real gTLD. See [Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

Comment: @DavidPostill In this particular case, I'm looking at configs which were written 2+ years ago and have barely been used in the meanwhile.

Comment: *shrug*. Time for change ...

Answer (score 3):

#### In February, Firefox began to force .dev requests to https.

This is because `.dev` has been bought by Google as one of their 100+ new gTLDs.

It is unlikely that Firefox and Chrome will make changes to their browsers, so you will have to consider making a change to your development environment.

> With .dev being an official gTLD, we're most likely better of changing
>   our preferred local development suffix from .dev to something else.
>
> If you're looking for a quick "search and replace" alternative for
>   existing setups, consider the .test gTLD, which is a reserved name by
>   IETF for testing (or development) purposes.
>
> There's also an excellent proposal to add the .localhost domain as a
>   new standard, which would be more appropriate here. It would mean we
>   no longer have site.dev, but site.localhost. And everything at
>   *.localhost would automatically translate to 127.0.0.1, without /etc/hosts or dnsmasq workarounds.

Source [Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it with a Firefox configuration change:

1. Visit the address `about:config`
2. Search for the parameter `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` and change it’s value to `false`.

*Source: [How to prevent Firefox and Chrome from forcing dev and foo domains to use https](https://tutoref.com/how-to-prevent-firefox-and-chrome-from-forcing-dev-and-foo-domains-to-use-https/)*

Comment: Nov '23 - Does not work for me.