# Firefox allow HTTP URLs (and not force HTTPS)

Tags: firefox, http, https, security-policy, security-warning

**tl;dr** I want to browse an `http`-based URL but Firefox will not let me.

A local network HTTP server is at `http://host` (port 80) and the corresponding HTTPS server is at `https://host` (port 443).

When I type into the Firefox Address Bar `http://host`<kbd>⏎</kbd>, Firefox insists on changing the URL to `https://host`.
Using the *Web Developer Tools* -> *Network* tab, I can see Firefox goes directly to `https://host` despite my entry of `http://host`. Firefox is not receiving an HTTP 300 Redirect from the server.

**How do I instruct Firefox to not overwrite `http` with `https`?

How do I instruct Firefox to connect to `http://host`?**

Using Firefox 100 on Windows 10.

Comment: I commend your attention to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs#firefox:win10:fx100

Comment: Did your HTTPS server perhaps, at any point in the recent past, serve a HSTS header?

Comment: also, if you haven't enabled HTTPS-Only mode, and have never had HSTS on the HTTPS version of the site,look at this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959914 . Once you have visited a site in HTTPS the address bar will remember and always prefer HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks @JeffZeitlin. The setting was already set to _Don’t enable HTTPS-Only Mode_.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB . In my case, according to the _Network_ tab, the selection of _https_ instead of _http_ occurs _before_ any HTTP communication occurs. Also, in the _Network_ tab, I checked _Disable Cache_. ⠀⠀⠀However, you wrote "_any point in the recent past, serve a HSTS header_".  Firefox reported "_host has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)_".  This may be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas . It appears that at some point the host returned an HSTS header. When I connect to `http://host`, the browser forces it to become `https://host`, then Firefox stops with a warning "_Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to host because this website requires a secure connection.
host has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)_".

Comment: An immediate workaround I found is to use the IP Address of the host, e.g. `http://192.168.0.1`. Then I was able to connect via `http` (to port 80). This is likely because no HSTS header ([`Strict-Transport-Security`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)) has been seen by Firefox for that host association.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon: HSTS _cannot_ apply to a host identified by IP-address [by design](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#appendix-A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** use the IP Address

#### IP Address

Instead of browsing to a URL of the named host, e.g. `http://host`, browse to the URL of the IP Address, e.g. `http://192.168.1.2`.

Firefox and other browsers will not forcibly insist on `https` protocol if *Don’t enable HTTPS-Only Mode* is set.

In *Settings* page (`about:preferences`), section *Privacy & Security*, change *HTTPS-Only Mode* to *Don’t enable HTTPS-Only Mode*

[image: HTTPS-Only Mode]

#### Other configurations to consider

- in `about:config` page, change `browser.fixup.fallback-to-https` to `false` (thanks @ubfan1)
- search "HTTPS" and tweak other settings until you have it

Related, browsing to the IP Address URL also allows an opportunity to skip TLS certificate checking for `https` connections.

Comment: Wish it were true, but Firefox 106.0.4 still insists on using https on IP address connections.  Even if exceptions are added to the "use https" and even if "don't use https" is checked.  Maybe you have some other setting which actually will allow http?

Comment: @ubfan1 I tested it again and still works for me. Using Firefox 106.0.3. I have set _HTTPS-Only Mode_ to option _Don’t enable HTTPS-Only Mode_. Also have setting _Enable DNS over HTTPS_ as unchecked.  Using Private setting _Standard_. I also tested against a site not in my Bookmarks using a quickie HTTP server `python3 -m http.server 80`. I was able to browse the non-bookmarked site at `http://192.168.1.1:80`.

Comment: I confirm your test works on Ubuntu 22.04/Firefox 106.0.4.  My explicit problem is connecting to an old security camera -- Old TLS support only, so maybe some fallback to https before reporting https failed instead of : "connection refused" like Chrome does.

Comment: "_My explicit problem is connecting to an old security camera -- Old TLS support only_" try either 1. what does the Developer Tools -> Network tab report? investigate from there, or 2. get a really old version of Firefox https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Comment: I found that setting browser.fixup.fallback-to-https to false in about:config will prevent the https switch to http (and reverted the dozen or so other changes I had made on various https settings). So now I get the refused connection like Chrome.  I did try some TLS and SSL changes, but connection still refused.  Getting an old Firefox version looks like my best bet at this time -- an old program to connect to old devices. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Many sites nowadays use name-based virtual hosting. The IP address alone isn't enough. The hostname is a required ingredient.

Comment: @DanielB good point; some sites will fail because they require a hostname in the URI host field (not an IP address). Unfortunately, I do not know of any other solution. I tried the other answers and other comments but Firefox is very insistent on `https`.

Comment: In my case even using IP address Firefox is wrongly insisting on https... and my force option is not enabled. Only working in other browsers.

Comment: Did not work for me (Firefox 120)

Answer (score 4):

Neither

- `browser.fixup.fallback-to-https: false`
- `browser.urlbar.autoFill: false`
- HTTPS Only disabled in settings
- HTTPS Only enabled and correct exceptions set

and all possible combinations of them did the trick consequently, but

- `browser.fixup.alternate.protocol: http`

fixed it for me

Comment: None of those worked for me, but these did:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528804/210867 and https://superuser.com/a/1315172/278224

Comment: Similar question [How do I stop Firefox from forcing https:// on local development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093537/how-do-i-stop-firefox-from-forcing-https-on-local-development-server)

Comment: Did not work for me (Firefox 120)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this while using `dev` as an alias for 127.0.0.1 because I wanted to use a host header with nginx to access a virtual server.

Turns out that's now a real TLD and part of what's called the "preloadlist".  None of the above suggestions worked for me, but these did:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52528804/210867
- https://superuser.com/a/1315172/278224

Summary: set `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` to false

Comment: Instead of linking to other issues, just tell people to set `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` to `false`.

Comment: I could, but I wanted to give those posts the credit, and they also contain more context than I provided because I didn't feel like repeating it.  Just like how SO staff routinely mark a question as a duplicate and link to an older version...

Comment: The StackOverflow guidelines on a good answer are that including links is not a bad idea, but the rest of the answer should be self-sufficient. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Did not work for me (Firefox 120)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [HTTPS-Only Mode in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs) and check, if HTTPS-Only Mode is enabled.

Comment: Thanks @MBehrens. Good suggestion. However, the setting was already set to _Don’t enable HTTPS-Only Mode_. .

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was getting this same error while trying to go to http://192.168.x.x/somepage.html when actually I needed to be going to http://192.168.x.x:5000/somepage.html. When I had forgotten to include the port number, I was getting upgraded to https no matter what I tried. Once I included the appropriate port, it worked just fine with http.